# Using almost all of the data to train model

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have tested a decision tree model on data with a split ratio of 70% between train and test data. I'm satisfied with out of sample accuracy and lack of overfit. Now, I want to use the model to predict new cases. Now that I know the features used are capable of predicting with high accuracy, does it make sense to retrain the model with the same features but using 99.999% of data before making new predictions? My point is why leave out 30% of the data in training while I already know the model does not overfit?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible and in general there is nothing wrong with it. You just want to treat your test split as validation and wait for a real test set. But, note that the answer might also depend on the choice of ML model. In many models, this won't be a problem; especially in simple models like decision trees. You've already found the best hyper-parameters, or feature set to move on. On the contrary, in neural networks, you'll always need a validation set apart from your training to decide on early-stopping. Back-propagation algorithm needs to run an indefinite number of iterations, that is typically chosen via a validation set. Here, you wouldn't be able to train with all the data you have.